# Select From Multi-Value List with Where Clause

Tags: sql, ms-access, multivalue

I'm trying to select all `Projects` which have `Employees` who are `AtWork`.

```
Projects:
ProjName    |    EmpOnProj
--------------------------
Alpha       |    1, 2, 3
Beta        |    1, 3

Employees:
EmpID       |   EmpName    |   AtWork
-------------------------------------
1           |   John       |   TRUE
2           |   Mark       |   FALSE
3           |   Mary       |   TRUE
```

I need to output all projects which could currently be worked on; ie, I need to show `Beta` because the employees working on Beta are at work.

Currently I cannot say "ALL EMPLOYEES MUST BE AT WORK" only the following:

```
SELECT ProjName FROM Projects INNER JOIN 
Employees ON EmpOnProj.Value = EmpID
WHERE AtWork = true
GROUP BY ProjName
```

which returns both, as it sees one correct employee and displays the project.

Comment: Your table seems to indicate a different structure for the Projects table than what your SQL provides. Are the EmpOnProj values actually on separate rows, or does your table need normalized?

Comment: Not sure how Access does it, but because this is just a quick home-use system (the employee thing was a simplification), I used the Multi-Value option of a combo box. Somehow, the `EmpOnProj.Value = EmpID` works, meaning it seems to search through the CSV as you would want it to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I solved this one. Basically I'm saying 'show all projects except those where somebody is NOT at work'

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/36c48/2

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  p_global.ProjName 

FROM
  Projects AS p_global

WHERE
  p_global.ProjName NOT IN
    (SELECT DISTINCT
      p1.ProjName

    FROM 
      Projects p1 INNER JOIN Employees AS e ON p1.EmpOnProj = e.EmpID 

    WHERE
      e.AtWork = 0)
```

There may be a simpler solution but this works (or it looks like it anyway) :)

Edit: Modified to remove `GROUP BY`s as suggested in comments.

Comment: Oh and as Fred pointed out, your question is harder to answer because your tables are not normalized.

Comment: But my solution does not assume normalized tables, it works with your table layout as it is right now.

Comment: Looks good, can simplify by not having to group but just do a distinct:

SELECT 
  DISTINCT p_global.ProjName 

FROM
  Projects AS p_global

WHERE
  p_global.ProjName NOT IN
    (SELECT 
      p1.ProjName
    
    FROM 
      Projects p1 INNER JOIN Employees AS e ON p1.EmpOnProj = e.EmpID 
    
    WHERE
      e.AtWork = 0)

Answer (score 1):

If can't really answer your question but this stuff can guide you through simplification and can help you solve you question. Currently your table is not in good format. Instead of having comma separated values, why not do it in rows instead? Like this,

```
Projects:
ProjName    |    EmpOnProj
--------------------------
Alpha       |    1
Alpha       |    2
Alpha       |    3
Beta        |    1
Beta        |    3
```

In this way you can easily join both tables. Example

```
SELECT  a.EmpID, a.EmpName, 
        iif (ISNULL(b.EmpOnProj), 'False', 'True') AtWork
FROM    Employees a
        LEFT JOIN Projects b
            ON a.EmpID = b.EmpOnProj
WHERE   b.ProjName = 'Beta'
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you move beyond the EmpOnProj column, which, as implemented in your example, violates [first normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form), and replace it with an associative entity called ProjEmp, whose primary key is (ProjName, EmpID)

```
SELECT p.ProjName FROM Projects p
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(SELECT eop.ProjName FROM ProjEmp eop
    INNER JOIN JOIN Employees e
    ON e.EmpId = eop.EmpId
    AND e.AtWork = FALSE
) AS empNotHere
ON empNotHere.ProjName = p.ProjName
WHERE empNotHere.ProjName IS NULL
;
```

Comment: No guarantees if this will actually work in MS Access, but it's about as vanilla as can be.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming I misunderstood your question since your SQL seems to contradict the schema you provided. But if your table is formatted the way you listed, you have to jump through hoops. Here's a solution that involves making a UDF, to avoid extremely complicated SQL.

Add this to a module:

```
Function WhoIsAtWork() As String
    Dim rs As Recordset
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select * from Employees where AtWork = true Order by EmpID")
    Do While Not rs.EOF
        WhoIsAtWork = WhoIsAtWork & rs!EmpID & ", "
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
    If Len(WhoIsAtWork) <> 0 Then
        WhoIsAtWork = Left(WhoIsAtWork, Len(WhoIsAtWork) - 2)
    End If
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
End Function
```

Then your SQL would be this:

```
SELECT ProjName
FROM Projects
WHERE Projects.EmpOnProj=WhoIsAtWork();
```